# jQuery accordion: remove active class when clicking active label

Tags: jquery, accordion

I've got a simple accordion that allows all to collapse. So clicking on the active panel collapses it. I have `before` and `after` pseudo-classes assigned for the arrows, but I can't figure out how to remove the active class from the active label when clicking on it to collapse it. Active class will be removed if clicking on a different label, but not if clicking on the active label to collapse it.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yNGa/).

And here's the script:

```
$(".accordion > dt").click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('.accordion > dd').slideUp(600);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(600);
});
```

I've tried a couple of different configurations (e.g., reversing the `if(false)` statement and removing `active` class), but everything I've tried has been a shot in the dark. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
    $(".accordion > dt").click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.accordion > dd').slideUp(600);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(600);
});
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you! I can accept your answer in six minutes. :)

Comment: That was a really simple solution too. Geez. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

using `toggleClass()` and `siblings()`

try this

```
    $(".accordion > dt").click(function(){
    //$('.active').removeClass('active');
         $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('dt').removeClass();

          if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $('.accordion > dd').slideUp(600);
          }
       $(this).next().slideToggle(600);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Bipen. This works also, though Ganesh had already answered. But I learned from this as well. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is because your active class is added to the `dt` element each time you click. You only add the active class if there are no active classes present that means if none of the `dd` elements are visible. So you need to change to

```
$(".accordion > dt").click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('.accordion > dd').slideUp(600);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(600);
});
```

Check the [Updated Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yNGa/1/).

Comment: Thanks, Kishor. Yeah, Ganesh D beat you with this answer by about five minutes so the green arrow goes to him, but thanks for this. It's so obvious now that you guys have pointed it out. Much appreciated.